# Laravel Scheduler fire 2 Commands at different times

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have 1 custom `Command` I've created:

`php artisan protal:process {name}`

I need to fire this command for 2 different Portals (different `name`), so If I run this in my console everything works:

```
php artisan protal:process nameone
//wait for it to finish
php artisan protal:process nametwo
```

I need to do the same at night with a cron, so this is what I came up with:

app/console/Kernel.php

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('portal:process nameone')->daily()->withoutOverlapping();
    $schedule->command('portal:process nametwo')->dailyAt('00:10')->withoutOverlapping();
}
```

For some reasons only the first command fires and the second one gets ignored. If I run the second one commenting the first one it works ok.

Perhaps to fire 2 commands in different times do I have to take some different method other than the above?

Comment: I've had this problem before. The problem was that I never properly closed the first command (with a `return` for example), which caused Laravel to think the command never ended and never started the next command as a result. PHP executes line for line, so the problem is probably in the `withoutOverlapping`. But to answer that, we need to see what is actually in your commands.

Comment: Thank you'I've added a return true if the commands goes well. Is there a way to encapsulate the command so that the second one runs even if the first doesn't?

Comment: @Loek your comment was good and it fixed the reason. If you place it as answer I'll check it. Ciao

Comment: Glad to help! Added as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added as answer for reference, was a comment:

I've had this problem before. The problem was that I never properly closed the first command (with a return for example), which caused Laravel to think the command never ended and never started the next command as a result. PHP executes line for line, so the problem is probably in the `withoutOverlapping`.